# How to debug and execute the below code

Tags: shell-script

```
echo "Enter the password"

read a
    if [ $a == anand ]
        then
            process_good;;
        else
            process_bad;;
    fi

process_good()
{
    echo "Enter the value"
    read m
    echo "$m"
} 

process_bad()
{
    echo "Bad password" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug, run your script and see where it fails and then adjust based on the errors.

Your functions will need to be defined before you call them.  For example:

```
function process_good(){
    echo "Enter the value"
    read m
    echo "$m"
    }

function process_bad(){
    echo "Bad password"
    }

echo "Enter the password"
read a

if [ $a == "anand" ]
then
    process_good
else
    process_bad
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-x` option for debugging a shell script.

`sh -x test_script.sh`

[See man page for more details](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=&n=1)